# C++ How to select option from the menu after typing a string before the menu?

Tags: c++, string, selection, iostream, submenu

I'm new to C++ and I'm developing a program where the students key in their subject code and then there will be a menu which has options to select from.

The problem is, after typing and entering the subject code, the menu and its options will appear but you exit the system instead of selecting the option to continue..

Here are the codes for the parts I'm trying to get them to work

```
    void ProcessStudent(char option, char subjCode)
    {
        fstream binFile;
const char *fileName;

cout << "Welcome to Priya's UOW Student File Processing\n" << endl;
cout << "Enter the module: ";
cin >> subjCode;

cout << "\n1. Creation of binary file\n";
cout << "2. Append a record\n";
cout << "3. Update a record\n";
cout << "4. Delete a record\n";
cout << "5. Produce final file (text file)\n";
cout << "9. Quit\n";

cout << "Your option: ";
cin >> option;

cout << "\n" <<setw(60)<<setfill('-')<<'-'<<endl;

switch(option)
{
    case '1':
        CreateBinary(binFile,subjCode,fileName);
    break;

    case '2':
        AppendRec(binFile,option,fileName);
    break;

    case '3':
        UpdateRec(binFile,option,fileName);
    break;

    case '4':
        DeleteRec(binFile,option,fileName);
    break;

    case '5':
        FinalFile(binFile,option,fileName);
    break;

    case '9':
        MainMenu(option);
}
    }

    void CreateBinary(fstream& binFile, char subjCode, const char *fileName)
    {
    //    Student s;

srand(time(NULL));

        binFile.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);

    //    binFile >> s.id;
    //    binFile.getline(s.name,MAX);

if(!binFile)
{
    cout << fileName << " opened for creation failed" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

cout << "Begin creation of " << fileName << endl;

fstream txtFile;
txtFile.open(fileName, ios::in);

if(!txtFile)
{
    cout << fileName << " opened for reading failed" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

cout << "Text file " << fileName << "opened for reading" << endl;



binFile.close();
txtFile.close();

cout << "Binary file " << fileName << " created" << endl;
cout << "Text file " << fileName << " closed for reading" << endl;
}
```

What I'm asking is, how can I select an option after I entered the subject code or any other string? Did I miss anything in the code?

Hope you guys understand what I'm asking, if not let me know.

Any help provided, is appreciated. Many thanks :).

Comment: Which compiler, how did you compile, which operating system? And show more code, and explain how you are debugging it.

Comment: i use the Quincy to compile. Sadly, I can't screen shot the program because of the reputation..sorry.

Comment: [Quincy](http://www.codecutter.net/tools/quincy/) is *not* a compiler (just an IDE). It is apparently using [Gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and `gdb`; you could compile on the command line (and you should do it a few times)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush the `cout` stream:

```
 cout << "Enter the module: " << flush;
```

and later

```
 cout << "Your option: "  << flush;
```

at last replace the output of newlines with `cout << endl`

and you should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb` perhaps). Perhaps some of the functions e.g. `UpdateRec` is crashing...

Comment: what do you mean by **flush the cout stream** ?

Comment: GIYF: see [flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) member function in `std::ostream` and the [flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/flush-free/) manipulator.